# AWS - Docker Swarm on 1 EC2 possible (for training)?

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker-swarm, docker-machine

Is it possible to create a Docker Swarm on 1 AWS EC2? Of course this is for training purposes.

If possible, what are the steps to create a manager and 2 workers on that 1 EC2?

Can I use the public URL of the AWS to use the docker swarm commands? 
And the same URL for reaching the docker services / stack items?

Comment: I have not tested this on ec2 but you can try to achieve this with multipass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is of course possible to turn Docker Swarm on in a (regular) Docker environment.

As normal, just use the following command:

$ docker swarm init

You will see the default node (as Leader). Now you can move forward using the regular 'docker stack deploy' command.